# Automating Windows 7 setup

Tags: windows-7, deployment

How do I create an iso which automatically enters product key,activates windows,selects timezone,creates users,randomely names the PC and gets it ready to go?

I need help....

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows Automated Installation Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343(WS.10).aspx) and [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx) are your best friends here.

Answer (score 0):

[nLite is a tool](http://www.nliteos.com/nlite.html) for pre-installation Windows configuration and component removal at your choice. Optional bootable image ready for burning on media or testing in virtual machines.
With nLite you will be able to have Windows installation which on install does not include, or even contain on media, the unwanted components.

[How To Image and Deploy Windows 7 a Complete Guide – Using sysprep and imagex](http://benosullivan.co.uk/windows/how-to-image-and-deploy-windows-7-a-complete-guide/)

[Windows 7 Setup Customization With Win Integrator](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-setup-customization-with-win-integrator/)

Video: [Preparing an Image using Sysprep and ImageX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee530017.aspx)

Comment: nLite is a tool for creating a cut down version of Windows. It will not do any of the things the OP has asked for, so why even mention it?

Comment: Yes it will, bootable ISO for example and these too: •Service Pack Integration •Component Removal •Unattended Setup •Driver Integration * •Hotfixes Integration ** •Tweaks •Services Configuration •Patches *** •Bootable ISO creation

Comment: http://www.rt7lite.com/downloads.html